# Not getting List View on DIalog box

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Problem is with its showing me nullpointer exception while click onshowContact button there is something wrong i cant figure it out but I m not getting the dialog box with the list view with this code
Button click of contact view

```
public void showContacts(View view){
        //View CSV into an array
        try{
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(NewMessage.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);
        dialog.setTitle("Contacts");

        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        int fillarray = 0;
        if(mylist.equals(null)){
            fillarray = 0; 
        }
        else{
            fillarray = mylist.size();
        }*/
        for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
        {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name",name.get(i));
            map.put("number",number.get(i));
            map.put("status",status.get(i));
            mylist.add(map);
        }
        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(NewMessage.this, mylist, R.layout.view_csv, new String[] {"name","number","status"}, new int[] {R.id.t1,R.id.t2,R.id.t3});
        lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    dialog.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, e.toString(), 2000).show();
        }
//Viewing Finish Here

    }
```

This my contact_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="397dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This my view_csv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"/>
     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text2"/>
      <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text3" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I m running the same code without using the dialog box its running perfectly and while opening the dialog box without the listview code dialog box running perfectly merging them gives me error

Comment: It is showing dialog box ???

Comment: When both code put together its not showing the dialog box too

Comment: If the ListView is in the Dialog's layout, then `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv)` is returning null.

Comment: Means i dint get u Mike

Comment: I have put toast after every line to detect an error and got something like its giving nullpointer exception at lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListView is comming under `contact_view` layout. So you have to initialize the list through your dialog. because your dialog contains the layout here `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);`

So you have to initialize the list like:

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
```